# Reading a date, time text file and converting to string using strptime()?

Tags: r

I have a text file of many rows containing date and time and the end goal is for me to group together the number of rows per week that their date values are in. This is so that I can plot a scatter diagram with x values being the week number and y values being the frequency. For example the text file (dates.txt):

```
Mon May 11 22:51:27 2013
Mon May 11 22:58:34 2013
Wed May 13 23:15:27 2013
Thu May 14 04:11:22 2013
Sat May 16 19:46:55 2013
Sat May 16 22:29:54 2013
Sun May 17 02:08:45 2013
Sun May 17 23:55:15 2013
Mon May 18 00:42:07 2013
```

So from here, `week 1 will have a frequency of 6` and `week 2 will have a frequency of 1`

As I want to plot a scatter diagram for this, I want to convert them to text value first using strptime() with format `%a %b`

my attempt so far has been

```
time_stamp <- strptime(time_stamp, format='%a.%b')
```

However it shows the input string is too long. I'm very new to R-studio so could somebody please help me figure this out?

Thank you

Example of final output graph : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeCN6.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `readLines()` to avoid the data frame, then read time using `strptime`, and finally `strftime` to format the output.

```
strftime(strptime(readLines('dates.txt'), '%c'), '%a.%b')
# [1] "Sat.May" "Sat.May" "Mon.May" "Tue.May" "Thu.May" "Thu.May" "Fri.May" "Fri.May" "Sat.May"
```

#### Edit

So it appears that your dates have a time zone abbreviation `"Mon Apr 06 23:49:29 PDT 2009"`. Since it is constant during the dates we can specify it literally in the pattern.

We will use `'%d_%m'` for `strftime` to get something numeric seperated by `_` with which we feed `strsplit` and then `type.convert` into numerics.

Finally we `unlist`, create a `matrix` that we fill `byrow`, and `plot` the guy.

```
strptime(readLines('timestamp.txt'), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S PDT %Y') |>
  strftime('%d_%m') |>
  strsplit('_') |>
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE) |>
  unlist() |>
  matrix(ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) |>
  plot(pch=20, col=4, main='My Plot', xlab='day', ylab='month')
```

[image]

**Note:** Please use [R>=4.1](https://www.r-project.org/) for the `|>` pipes.

Comment: Thank you for your input, trying the code and it shows NA NA NA. This may be due to my large file (I have around 1k of these lines), do you have any suggestions of how I should proceed? ps. I edited my post to show the error :) Thank you so much

Comment: @Mateybro The `'%c'` might be locale specific, could you try `'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the output is the same error as the previous code (NANANA). I'm using Rstudio cloud

Comment: @Mateybro If it works when you copy your sample dates into the .txt file as I did, I suspect that your original dates are slightly different. Could you test that?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried with the sample text on my post and it works, yes my dates are slightly different as my text file is a lot larger than the 9 rows of my sample post. I have around 1.6 k rows to be exact. Is there a way I can work around that?

Comment: apologies for the inconvenience, but is there a way to group these values by week. I can see the use of %a and %b in the code, but since I will be plotting them down on a scatter diagram later, I'm not sure how the output will allow me to do that. I apologize for bothering you so much, could you please help me see this through?

Comment: @Mateybro It's rather a matter of how the dates are formatted, how are they exactly formatted, and do the formats change during the rows?

Comment: @Mateybro Interesting, so you want coordinates for each point, that should not be much of a problem if we fix the first issue.

Comment: I don't think my date format has changed, but for better context I have copied and pasted the entire text file into here: https://pastebin.com/7tvfE6mp 
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Mateybro See edit, what do you think?

Comment: I see what you did! Thank you for the new edit and the helpful explanation, this will definitely help me later! There's a slight issue with the output though as I will need to plot the frequency of how many values appear per week. This is sorta like the output on the other reply to my post. Like this [ https://imgur.com/a/3o3DivA ]. I see that the output from your end is how often the value comes up on a particular day per month, which is definitely helpful in the future. Could you please take a look at it again. Thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238006/discussion-between-jay-sf-and-matey-bro).

Answer (score 1):

You need to first *read* (or assign) the data, parse it to a date type and then use that to *e.g.* get the number of the week.

Here is one example

```
text <- "Mon May 11 22:51:27 2013
Mon May 11 22:58:34 2013
Wed May 13 23:15:27 2013
Thu May 14 04:11:22 2013
Sat May 16 19:46:55 2013
Sat May 16 22:29:54 2013
Sun May 17 02:08:45 2013
Sun May 17 23:55:15 2013
Mon May 18 00:42:07 2013"

data <- read.table(text=text, sep='\n', col.names="dates")
data$parse <- anytime::anytime(data$dates)
data$week <- as.integer(format(data$parse, "%V"))

data
```

The result is a new `data.frame` object:

```
> data
                     dates               parse week
1 Mon May 11 22:51:27 2013 2013-05-11 22:51:27   19
2 Mon May 11 22:58:34 2013 2013-05-11 22:58:34   19
3 Wed May 13 23:15:27 2013 2013-05-13 23:15:27   20
4 Thu May 14 04:11:22 2013 2013-05-14 04:11:22   20
5 Sat May 16 19:46:55 2013 2013-05-16 19:46:55   20
6 Sat May 16 22:29:54 2013 2013-05-16 22:29:54   20
7 Sun May 17 02:08:45 2013 2013-05-17 02:08:45   20
8 Sun May 17 23:55:15 2013 2013-05-17 23:55:15   20
9 Mon May 18 00:42:07 2013 2013-05-18 00:42:07   20
>
```

Comment: your output looks perfect :) Thank you for your suggestion. However, I need to perform this task using strptime() and my text file is timestamp.txt, so all of my example input is in a single column, hence when I try the code given, it doesn't show me the week column as above. My apologies. Are further suggestions welcome please :)

Comment: Just use strptime, it is well documented how to derive the format. I fine the `anytime` function helpful as I skip that step, but both ways work equally well.  (Disclaimer: I wrote `anytime`.)